# Do we refer to conifers wood or resin wood when speaking of softwood?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I would like to know which term is being used when speaking of softwood. Would we say conifers wood or resin wood? Or we would simply say softwood?

How should I correctly write in a quotation sheet about this kind of timber I offer?

Comment: *deal* is another word for that.

Comment: @MaulikV *Deal* is very little used in the US.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the US timber industry *softwood* is the standard term for wood from gymnosperm trees, and *hardwood* for wood from angiosperm trees.

All conifers are gymnosperms, and therefore their timber is *softwood*. I don't remember ever encountering either 'conifer wood' or 'resin wood' in my scene-carpentry days.

Practically, however, no one buys *hardwood* or *softwood*: they buy Scotch pine or white pine or oak or beech, or whatever wood best suits the project at hand. *Hardwood* and *softwood* are just categories for organizing the list of woods you offer.

Comment: Thank you! You are right, but I needed a generic term before referring to specific cases.

Comment: @LucianSava *Softwood*, then, at least for the US market. If you are trading internationally you probably want to check usage in each of your markets and draw up distinct pricelists.

Comment: Much obliged! Your advice is very useful too.